# Is social media Sign in totally free?

Tags: android, ios, authentication, google-signin

How much is the cost of having social media authentication on an Android or Ios app?

Is there an social media provider, authenticator, that cost less or more when having a log of users, about 200 000 user sign ins every month?

The Azure AD B2C was free up to 50 000, but more users cost 0.02$ per user. Do the social media providers like Google and Twitter cost when you exceed a specific limit?

Which one is the most cost effective, is there any calculations that can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Social Media Authentication totally is free and You can implement that in your `Android Application`, `iOS Application` and in your `Web Application` very easily using [Firebase Authentication By Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/).

You can even use a pre-built User Interface that Let you Authenticate users in a single line of code. That is called FirebaseUI, you can find documentation of FirebaseUI [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui)